# Посчитать процент от значения между двумя точками

Tags: математика, формулы, арифметика

Даны 3 значения

1. Минимальное значение 100 это 10%
2. Максимальное значение 1600 это 80%
3. Полученное значение 460 это **X**%

Надо из этих данных понять 3е значение в процентах между 10% и 80%
Подскажите, как тут корректно можно посчитать.

Comment: Составьте пропорцию - 70% приходятся на 1500 единиц. Прикиньте значение на единицу, посчитайте проценты для 460-100, а потом добавьте их к 10%...

Comment: Спасибо, но все ровно не понимаю как это технически посчитать, просто логика вообще не понятная с числами получается, если 100 это 10% то 1000 это 100 должно быть, но у нас 1600 представлено как 80%. Такое вообще может быть условие?) 
Может просто менеджер придумал что-то не реальное и надо изменить условие задачи.

Comment: А кто вам сказал, что ноль - это ноль процентов?...

Comment: А проценты точно прирастают линейно?

Comment: @Akina А тогда решения просто нет. Вернее, их бесконечно много...

Comment: @Harry Да кто ж его знает... может, есть вполне определённая зависимость - формулой али графиком.

Answer (score 4):

Так понятно? Простая пропорция...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, так очень понятно)

Comment: а ответ изображением считается ответом? ;)

Comment: @Jack_oS Изображение хранится на ruSO, так что вроде бы вполне..